# How to intercept a 404 Not Found using the OWIN pipeline

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I have another question to do with Web-API and OWIN. I am "playing" with it, trying to learn about it, and I wanted to see if I could intercept a 404 on the "way back" from the web api.

So, I have the following in my Startup..

```
app.Use(async (environment, next) =>
      {       
        Debug.WriteLine(environment.Request.Uri);
        await next();   
        Debug.WriteLine(environment.Response.StatusCode);
      });

  HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
  WebApiConfig.Register(config);
  app.UseWebApi(config);
```

I then do a GET (in a browser) using an invalid URI so that I get a 404 result. I expected to see this as the status code written out in the Debug.WriteLine(environment.Response.StatusCode)

However, all I see (in dev studio output window , as I am running IIS express) is

```
http://localhost:55905/myresource
http://localhost:55905/myresource
200
200
```

I really expected to the the 404 in there.

Does anyone know why we don't see the 404 coming back?

I have looked through the Response, and cannot see it anywhere.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: 401 = Unauthorized. 404 = Not Found.

Comment: DOH! Yes I had an error in the title. I meant the 404. Fixed the title, but the question still remains
Cheers

Comment: @peterc Did you ever figure out what was happening here?  I am encountering a similar issue.

Comment: @Joshua Barron No, I never did find this out. Something I would still like to know, will have to get back to it soon. If you find out first, I would be very interested.

Answer (score 0):

Is `/myresource` a valid webapi route?
I think (but I'm not sure) your request is handled by IIS directly ignoring the owin-pipeline. But I don't know why its responding with a 200.
You can test it really easy.
Assuming your code and the following configuration:

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );
    }
}
```

And modified your Startup class a little:

```
app.Use(async (environment, next) => {
    Debug.WriteLine(environment.Request.Uri);

    environment.Response.OnSendingHeaders(_ => {
        var resp = ((IOwinResponse) _);
        Debug.WriteLine("Headers are send!: {0}", resp.StatusCode);
        resp.Headers.Add("X-MyTag", new[] {"Nice value!"});

    }, environment.Response);
    await next();
    Debug.WriteLine(environment.Response.StatusCode);
});
```

Sample controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController {
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Now the OWIN Pipeline should return in EACH request a custom header X-MyTag.
I'm using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect my request.

A request to `http://localhost:13543/` responds without my header. So it isn't served by the owin pipeline.
On the other hand a request to `http://localhost:13543/api/Values` responds with a 200 and my custom header.

An (invalid) request to `http://localhost:13543/api/Values1` responds with 404 including my custom header AND you can see this 404 in your output console.